# TinyMCE Editor is stripping out empty href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, editor

I am working with TinyMCE but I notice that the editor is stripping out the href attribute if is empty.
I want this:

```
<a href="">some text</a>
```

But the editor removes the *href* attribute and this is the unwanted result:

```
<a>some text</a>
```

I tried using this parameters in the init function:

```
cleanup: false,
verify_html: false,
allow_script_urls: true,
valid_elements: '*[*]',
```

But I am still not having good luck.

Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use `<a href="#">Some text</a>` ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
convert_urls: false,
remove_script_host: false,
verify_html: false,
valid_children: "+a[div|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|h6|p|#text]",
```